# Fastest datatype in java for retrieving integers in the same order as stored

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, integer, iteration

I need to write a program which will get very large number of input integers, about 10^6 numbers and process them in the same order. Which data structure will be the fastest in iteration..? The program must run within 3 seconds.

Comment: Why do you need to store them at all?  Just process them as you read them.

Comment: I suppose you can use `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` (or even an array). 10^6 integers isn't so much as you think.

Comment: You should process them as you read them. The bottleneck will be doing your process more than loading up the next number anyway. But if you know how many values you are going to get. An array is the fastest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iteration in the same order you can use a simple [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) if performance is a critical issue (but it does not allow growing the array dynamically without some extra effort, so you should usually be aware of the final size of the array in order to use it).

You can also use a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface. Both [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) support efficient iterating and appending. This allows better maintainability for your code, but suffers from slightly worse performances.

Answer (score 0):

First, [Premature Optimization is the Root of All Evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).  The idea that you need to go "as fast as possible" without having measured the actual run time of your program is just nonsense.  You should write clear concise code, then measure performance and optimize only if needed.

That said, the fastest possible read is likely going to be a memory mapped file.

```
  File file = new File( "blah" );
  FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream( file ).getChannel();
  MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map( FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0,
          file.length() );
  IntBuffer ib = mbb.asIntBuffer();
```

However be aware that Java uses NIO and byte buffers internally and can usually optimize reads better than you can.  Here's a site that claims that [small byte buffer reads are actually faster](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly) in some cases.

```
  FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream( "blah" );
  FileChannel ch = f.getChannel();
  ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate( 1024*8 );
  long checkSum = 0L;
  int nRead;
  while( ( nRead = ch.read( bb ) ) != -1 ) {
     if( nRead == 0 )
        continue;
     bb.position( 0 );  // processes the byte buffer, this 
     bb.limit( nRead ); // example just computes a checksum
     while( bb.hasRemaining() )
        checkSum += bb.get();
     bb.clear();
```

Now read that article and remember what was mentioned about *measuring performance* before you make assumptions.